# Docker build fails on windows but works on linux

Tags: docker, npm

I have a `Dockerfile` which builds without problems on my linux computer (Ubuntu 20.04), but fails with the error `npm: not found` when I try to build it on a windows computer with a fresh installation of docker desktop.

I would expect that the build succeeds on both windows and linux.
I suspect that the windows docker installation is flawed, but I don't know how to proceed with the debugging and hope that someone can help.

The Dockerfile contains the following:

```
FROM python:3.8 as base
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm help
```

The output from building the docker container in linux is

```
$ docker build --no-cache  .
[+] Building 16.0s (10/10) FINISHED                                    docker:default
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                0.0s  
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 213B                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8                    0.0s
 => CACHED [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8                               0.0s
 => [2/6] RUN apt-get update                                                     2.1s
 => [3/6] RUN apt-get install -y curl                                            2.4s
 => [4/6] RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -            5.4s 
 => [5/6] RUN apt-get install -y nodejs                                          4.4s 
 => [6/6] RUN npm help                                                           0.8s 
 => exporting to image                                                           0.7s 
 => => exporting layers                                                          0.7s 
 => => writing image sha256:be62cb38a601050cbbaa1be0b476229e80f09260a7921352e76  0.0s
```

The output from building the docker container in windows is as follows

```
PS C:\Users\hemi\DockerExperiments> docker build --no-cache .
[+] Building 14.4s (9/9) FINISHED                           docker:default
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                  0.0s
=> => transferring dockerfile: 220B                                  0.0s
=> [internal] load .dockerignore                                     0.1s
=> => transferring context: 2B                                       0.0s
=> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8         0.6s
=> CACHED [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8@sha256:5416fd3804  0.0s
=> [2/6] RUN apt-get update                                          2.8s
=> [3/6] RUN apt-get install -y curl                                 1.4s
=> [4/6] RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash   3.7s
=> [5/6] RUN apt-get install -y nodejs                               5.2s
=> ERROR [6/6] RUN npm help                                          0.6s
------
> [6/6] RUN npm help:
0.541 /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
------
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |     RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
   5 |     RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
   6 | >>> RUN npm help
   7 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm help" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
PS C:\Users\hemi\DockerExperiments>
```

In linux I used this version of docker

```
$ docker version                      
Client: Docker Engine - Community                                                     
 Version:           24.0.5                                                            
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.6
 Git commit:        ced0996
 Built:             Fri Jul 21 20:35:23 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.5
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.6
  Git commit:       a61e2b4
  Built:            Fri Jul 21 20:35:23 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

And in windows I used this version

```
> docker version
Client:
Cloud integration: v1.0.35
Version:           24.0.2
API version:       1.43
Go version:        go1.20.4
Git commit:        cb74dfc
Built:             Thu May 25 21:53:15 2023
OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
Context:           default
Server: Docker Desktop 4.21.1 (114176)
Engine:
  Version:          24.0.2
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.4
  Git commit:       659604f
  Built:            Thu May 25 21:52:17 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```